# ResponseBody is not getting deserialized using restassured

Tags: json, rest, deserialization, pojo, rest-assured

When I try to deserialize the response body into POJO then null values are set and encountering and below error is seen when JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) is not used:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "City" (class TestNGMaven.restAssuredProject.WeatherInfo), not marked as ignorable (6 known properties: "humidity", "temperature", "weatherDescription", "city", "windSpeed", "windDirectionDegree"])

Below is the code which I am using:

```
    public class WeatherInfo
{
    private String city;
    private String temperature;
    private String humidity;
    private String weatherDescription;
    private String windSpeed;
    private String windDirectionDegree;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Method used:

```
public void getWeatherDetailsForCity(String city) {

        RestAssured.baseURI="http://restapi.demoqa.com/utilities/weather/city";

        Response response= given().
                when().
                get("/"+city)
                .then()
                .extract()
                .response();

        ResponseBody responseBody=response.body();
        //No issues in below code
        System.out.println(responseBody.asString());
        //Exception for the below lines
        WeatherInfo weatherInfo =responseBody.as(WeatherInfo.class);    
        System.out.println(weatherInfo.getCity());
```

Error:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "City" (class TestNGMaven.restAssuredProject.WeatherInfo), not marked as ignorable (6 known properties: "humidity", "temperature", "weatherDescription", "city", "windSpeed", "windDirectionDegree"])
 at [Source: (String)"{
    "City": "Hyderabad",
    "Temperature": "28.5 Degree celsius",
    "Humidity": "62 Percent",
    "WeatherDescription": "haze",
    "WindSpeed": "1.5 Km per hour",
    "WindDirectionDegree": " Degree"
}"

Also changing city to City is not solving the error.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by adding the below in the POJO class where I used GSON annotation style

```
@SerializedName("City")
    @Expose
    private String city;
```

And deserialized using the below format

```
WeatherInfo weatherInfo =responseBody.as(WeatherInfo.class,ObjectMapperType.GSON);
```